# hide/show div and button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code inside a form. However, when I click first on "Show section below", it quickly shows the "multmachines" div then this same button appears again and the div disappears.
I don't know why it doesn't work (it works fine if I put the buttons outside of the form but not inside). Any help please !!

```
<form name="input" action="" method="POST">
 <button class="close" id="hidemultmachines" onclick="$('#multmachines').hide();   $(this).hide();$('#showmultmachines').show();">Hide section below <img alt="Close" width="35" height="35" src="../images/close.png"> </button>
 <button class="close" id="showmultmachines" onclick="$('#multmachines').show();   $(this).hide();$('#hidemultmachines').show();"><img alt="Show" width="35" height="35" src="../images/arrow-down.png">Show section below</button>
 <div class="jumbotron" id="multmachines">
     <div class="divtable">
         <table id="hosts" class="table table-striped">
             <tr>
                 <th width="28%"><strong>Prefix</strong></th>
                 <th width="17%"><strong>Type</strong></th>
                 <th width="27%"><strong>Group</strong></th>
                 <th width="60%"><strong>Number of Machines</strong></th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td><input type="text" name="prefix" class="a1" size="16"></td>
                 <td><select name="machinestype" class="a1">
                     {html_options values=$types output=$types}
                     </select>
                 </td>
                 <td><select name="machinesrange" id=machinesrange class="a1">
                     {html_options values=$ranges output=$ranges}
                     </select>
                 </td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="machinesnumber" id=machinesnumber class="a1" size="32">
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
 </div> 
</form>
```

I precise that I have this code in the header, so it's not because of that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#hidemultmachines').hide();
   $('#multmachines').hide();
  });
```

**QUESTION UPDATED**

Comment: your code hide 'hidemultmachines', 'multmachines' on load, and what mean doesnt work? Remember to close the });

Comment: Yeah yeah it's closed it's just because there are lots of function that I took just the section related to my code

Comment: @Abderrahim how about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hX54p/) ?

Comment: its working fine, change as mentioned by Se0ng11 http://jsfiddle.net/6uG6S/2/

Answer (score 0):

The div hides because you hide every times when the jQuery is load do this only when you click the button.try to remove the onClick event and do this in jQuery like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hidemultmachines").click(function(){
$('#multmachines').hide();
  });
  $("#showmultmachines").click(function(){
    $("#multmachines").show();
  });
});
</script>
```

you can add this cript and you can easily hide and show your div on button click...
    and alsoe refer to the w3schools for jquery hide and show button..thanks...

Comment: i think it is a great site to help w3school...:) any one has its own experience

Comment: it is not a trustworthy resources and stop encouraging the user to use this. there are number of useful resources online

Comment: It doesn't work, I remind you that I have this code inside a form and that is the problem, cause without it it works pretty good

Answer (score 0):

Create main div and put two buttons and inside give your table content and multmachines div
Inside form is not worked
Try the following one:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Sample For Animation</title>


      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#showmultmachines').hide();
       $('#multmachines').hide();
      }</script>
    <body>
     <div class="jumbotron" id="multmachinescon">
     <button class="close" id="hidemultmachines" onclick="$('#multmachines').hide();   $(this).hide();$('#showmultmachines').show();">Hide section below <img alt="Close" width="35" height="35" src="../images/close.png"> </button>
     <button class="close" id="showmultmachines" onclick="$('#multmachines').show();   $(this).hide();$('#hidemultmachines').show();"><img alt="Show" width="35" height="35" src="../images/arrow-down.png">Show section below</button>
     <div class="jumbotron" id="multmachines">
     <div class="divtable">
     <table id="hosts" class="table table-striped">
     <tr>
     <th width="28%"><strong>Prefix</strong></th>
     <th width="17%"><strong>Type</strong></th>
     <th width="27%"><strong>Group</strong></th>
     <th width="60%"><strong>Number of Machines</strong></th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="prefix" class="a1" size="16"></td>
     <td><select name="machinestype" class="a1">
      {html_options values=$types output=$types}
     </select>
     </td>
     <td><select name="machinesrange" id=machinesrange class="a1">
      {html_options values=$ranges output=$ranges}
     </select>
     </td>
     <td><input type="text" name="machinesnumber" id=machinesnumber class="a1" size="32">
     </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     </div>
     </div></div> </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code at JSFiddle

```
<button class="close" id="hidemultmachines">Hide section below 
<img alt="Close" width="35" height="35" src="../images/close.png"> </button>
<button class="close" id="showmultmachines">
<img alt="Show" width="35" height="35" src="../images/arrow-down.png">Show section below</button>
<div class="jumbotron" id="multmachines">
 <div class="divtable">
     <table id="hosts" class="table table-striped">
         <tr>
             <th width="28%"><strong>Prefix</strong></th>
             <th width="17%"><strong>Type</strong></th>
             <th width="27%"><strong>Group</strong></th>
             <th width="60%"><strong>Number of Machines</strong></th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td><input type="text" name="prefix" class="a1" size="16"></td>
             <td><select name="machinestype" class="a1">
                 {html_options values=$types output=$types}
                 </select>
             </td>
             <td><select name="machinesrange" id=machinesrange class="a1">
                 {html_options values=$ranges output=$ranges}
                 </select>
             </td>
             <td><input type="text" name="machinesnumber" id=machinesnumber class="a1" size="32">
             </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#multmachines').hide();
    $('#hidemultmachines').hide();
  $("#hidemultmachines").click(function(){
    $('#multmachines').hide();
    $('#showmultmachines').show();
    $('#hidemultmachines').hide();
});
$("#showmultmachines").click(function(){
    $("#multmachines").show();
    $('#showmultmachines').hide();
    $('#hidemultmachines').show();
});
```

});

Here is the [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mehtaniravm/Ybq3G/)

Hope that works for you. :)

Comment: Thank's for helping, but it doesn't works !! in fact you don't try it inside a form. Try to do so and it won't work. I don't know why !! Try for example to put you code between this <form name="input" action="" method="get">...</form>.